# Xml parsing error: hexadecimal value is an invalid character

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, httpwebrequest, xmldocument

I try get xml file with this code:

```
HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
string xml = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
//xml = xml.Replace((char)(0x1F), ' ');
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
```

but I get exception as below:

```
' ', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
```

So according to many similar questions on stackoverflow I try add this commented line, but then I get exception:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 2.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `xml` before the call to `LoadXml`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It's weird string, like this: `�\b\0\0\0\0\0�ے�F��{�\b�C�D̎vl�\a$�j��%�G�%UH��n�X�H�*\b�\v ��ZӚ~�����݌�\\|��_�d�H�'�U��uO�L d�������[�C?�$���O�BZ�_������?�ˏo�rb�˟���0�i?�R��C1t\aj�t��7}`

Comment: ...but source xml is definitely correct

Comment: Is there any type of compression that is being applied to the XML?

Comment: @JGinSD Hmm, I think yes. If I run `url` in browser I get `*.xml` file wrapped in `*.bz` archive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the compression that is being applied to the XML is GZip you can uncompress the XML like so:

```
HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
string xml = string.Empty;
using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(response.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(gzip))
{
  xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
//xml = xml.Replace((char)(0x1F), ' ');
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
```

If the GZipStream does not work to decompress the XML you'll have to replace it with the appropriate decompression stream.